# Store Memory Resource from which an object was created to the object itself to be able to call delete as usual?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, c++20, delete-operator, allocator

When a memory resource (or allocator) is used to create an object, one needs to remember at deletion by which memory resource it was created.

Is it a good pattern to store the memory resource to the object itself and do the appropriate deletion in the class' delete operator? The following code shows the idea:

```
#include <memory_resource>

using namespace std::pmr;

struct A
{
    A (memory_resource * memres_ = nullptr)
      : memres(memres_)
    {}
    memory_resource * memres;

    void operator delete(A * this_, std::destroying_delete_t)
    {
        if ( memory_resource * memres_ = this_->memres )
            polymorphic_allocator(memres_).delete_object(this_);
        else
            ::delete(this_);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A * aGlobal = new A;
    delete aGlobal;

    memory_resource * memres = get_default_resource();
    A * aPmr = polymorphic_allocator(memres).new_object<A>(memres);
    delete aPmr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, how an object is destroyed should mirror how it is created. If you used `new T`, then you should use `delete pT`. If you allocate memory from some resource and then use placement new, then you should call the destructor and deallocate memory with that resource. And if you use `polymorphic_allocator::new_object`, you should mirror that use with `polymorphic_allocator::delete_object`.

Yes, this means that the code which owns an object (and therefore deletes it) needs to know *how* to delete it. But that's what ownership ultimately *means*.

Yes, you can make an object that knows how to delete itself. But that kind of confuses the issue. Consider your use case. If you pass a memory resource, then it can `delete` itself. If you use regular `new`, then it can `delete` itself. But if you use placement-`new` on some memory that *doesn't* come from a memory resource, then you have to avoid calling `delete` on it. That creates an inconsistency with how you allocate the object.

Put simply, objects don't allocate their own memory, so they shouldn't be expected to deallocate it either.

Comment: @shpc: Some code was responsible for creating the object. Code which is responsible for an object's creation is *also* responsible for its destruction. Such code can transfer that responsibility to some other code, but if that happens, then it must *also* ensure that it transfer enough information to allow the receiving code to destroy the object. So where to store it is "in the place that's destroying it".

Comment: Thanks for lot for your answer. I agree, the new/delete symmetry is broken by this. On the other hand the question is where to store the information how it was allocated. In a situation where multiple resources are used, there is a risk, the object is deallocated with the wrong  resource, so it seems to be obvious to store that information to the object itself. Could something along the lines of `std::enable_shared_from_this` with a custom deleter be a better pattern?